# MongoDB Datetimefield Null Error

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to save a null value in a `dateTimeField` object in MongoDB. I have a date I only want set after a certain condition has been fulfilled, but my site has the ability to save an object multiple time to the database before this variable will be set to anything other than a null or empty string value. I tried using `db.dateTimeField(null=True)` in my model file per [Mongo's documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html) to save a null value, but I still get an error when trying to save to the database.

According to this issue on [Github](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/734), there is some inconsistent behavior with setting null values to `dateTimeFields`. Does anyone know if this has been fixed? I have a work around (adding my attribute to my object, then assigning it a value right before saving, therefore bypassing the need to save a null value, but it is a bit hacky, and I would like to use MongoDB's built in functionality if possible).

Thanks in advance!